# Ubuntu replace expression in dir and all sub directories

Tags: grep, sed, find-and-replace

How can I replace an expresion that has a forward slash with another in all dirs and subdirs?

I used this to find:  `grep -rnw "/var/www/site" -e "app/COD1"`

And now I want to replace: "app/COD1" with "app2/COD2" in all the files.

I cd to the dir /var/www/site and tried with: `sed -i 's,app/COD1,app2/COD2,g' *`
and with `sed -i 's/'app/ABC'/'apps/ABC'/g' *`
with no luck...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the `-e` option to specify a command on the command line. Given that, the following works for me:

```
$ cat file.txt
app/COD1
app/COD2
app2/COD1
app/COD1
app/COD1
$ sed -i -e "s,app/COD1,app2/COD2,g" file.txt
$ cat file.txt
app2/COD2
app/COD2
app2/COD1
app2/COD2
app2/COD2
```

Using backslashes also works, in case you're replacing something that might have commas (or whatever delimiter you choose):

```
$ sed -i -e "s/app\\/COD1/app2\\/COD2/" file.txt
```

Comment: hello, the code works for a file, but as I stated in the title I need to replace that string in all the files from a dir and all sub directories. I tired with  sed -i -e "s,app/COD1,app2/COD2,g" *  but I receive an error at the first folder found: sed: couldn't edit bin: not a regular file

Comment: but it works like this:)  grep -rl 'app/COD1' /var/www/site | xargs sed -i -e "s,app/COD1,app2/COD2,g"

Comment: @danny2015 Ok, yes, I should have expanded to provide a "complete" solution using `xargs` or `while read`, although I didn't realize that was the part giving you problems. If you'd include the error from your first comment above in the question itself that would have made it clearer what problem you were seeing, "with no luck" isn't too useful. Glad my answer at least helped a bit though.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep -rl 'app/ABC' /opt/apps/ABC | xargs sed -i -e "s,app/ABC,apps/ABC,g"
```

Comment: Congratulations on solving your problem. However, even if you're answering your own question, we prefer that answers contain some explanation.